# Chaos Theory and Sum Subset Problem

Tags: np-complete, chaos-theory

In respect to the "P versus NP" controversy, can't chaos theory be used to solve problems like the Sum Subset Problem with non exponential performance?

Like, chaotic equations, are like paths to very different places, according to the door you chose at the beginning. So can't like a chaotic equation be created and then the door would be the Set, that is the numbers in the set would be encoded in a number that would be provided to the chaotic equation, and then you would get like a 0 or a 1, or the number of combinations like if you applied to the equation to itself a number of times equal to the size of the set? That would be polynomial, I believe.

I don't know about mathematics and only a few about computer science but maybe people more knowledgeable can do it.

Comment: Maybe it can, maybe it can't. Nobody's figured out a way to do it. The thing you have to remember is that it's easy to get a $0$ or a $1$ out of an equation. What's hard is to get a $1$ when the right answer is $1$ and to get a $0$ when the right answer is $0$! And to do that your chaotic system will have to figure out whether there is some subset of numbers whose sum is zero. It's hard to do that in a linear number of iterations because there are exponentially many subsets. So your chaotic equation would have to be very clever, very clever indeed...

Comment: This question may be conflating two different intuitions. It's true that the problems in NP exhibit "chaotic" behaviour, in that small differences in input lead in "non-monotonic" ways to significant differences in output. In SAT, for example, a change of one symbol in a (satisfiable) formula can lead to a completely different witness of satisfiability. The other idea is that small differences in *test witness* (the "nondeterministic" bit of NP) lead to differing outcomes and should rapidly cover enough of the space to find a witness if it exists. This is false: there may be only one witness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of chaotic dynamical systems in solving the (NP-hard) 3-sat problem has been studied. It turns out (so far) that while these methods provide an interesting way of looking at this problem, actually SOLVING them via solution of chaotic ODEs is WAY worse as far as (real)time performance is concerned, compared to state of the art combinatorial solvers. Theoretically, algorithm is polynomial continuous time, hence not polynomial discrete time.
For more information, please see : Optimization hardness as transient chaos in an analog approach to constraint satisfaction

http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0526